# RestKit image upload to web service

Tags: ios7, restkit, restkit-0.20

For a customer project, I need to upload an image (as a profile picture) to a backend web service. That service only wants the image in the body of the HTTP-POST request.

As I am using RestKit in the rest of my application, I want to use the library for this upload.
STO and Google only gave me answers by using a multipart-form.

Is there a workaround to skip the multipart-form and just send the image (without being attached to an object)?

I am using RestKit 0.20.3 and develop for iOS 7.

Comment: You can use be this library that will work on any kind of web service: github.com/mineshpurohit/ServiceCallingUtility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use RestKit for this, there is no mapping involved so it is not appropriate. RestKit uses AFNetworking which is appropriate for this task so use that instead.

If you just want the image in the post body, get the appropriately encoded image data and set it as the `HTTPBody` of your `NSMutableURLRequest`. Then use `AFHTTPRequestOperation` to send the request.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I was already trying a different approach, just like you mentioned :) So everything is working fine right now!